# Select rows when column value change in between date in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

Ex- I have Table A like data as below-

```
ID  Code    Date
1   A   19-Feb-18
1   B   18-Feb-18
1   B   17-Feb-18
1   B   16-Feb-18
2   A   17-Feb-18
2   B   16-Feb-18
3   A   17-Feb-18
3   A   16-Feb-18
4   D   16-Feb-18
```

Now i want result like:

**case 1**: If I need data between `16-feb-18` to `19-feb-18` then result should be like below

```
1   A   19-Feb-18
1   B   18-Feb-18
1   B   17-Feb-18
1   B   16-Feb-18
2   A   17-Feb-18
2   B   16-Feb-18
```

it will exclude record for Id 3 and 4 because there are no changes in given date.

**case 2**: If I need data between `16-feb-18` to `18-feb-18` then result should be like below

```
2   A   17-Feb-18
2   B   16-Feb-18
```

it will exclude record for Id 1,3 and 4 because there are no changes in given date.

Comment: I do not understand. Changes to what? Within what?

Comment: You should [use analytical `count()`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3c86e/1).

Comment: In particular date range we need only those id for which code is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option (you need lines 12 onwards):

```
SQL> with test (id, code, datum) as
  2  (select 1, 'a', date '2018-02-19' from dual union all
  3   select 1, 'b', date '2018-02-18' from dual union all
  4   select 1, 'b', date '2018-02-17' from dual union all
  5   select 1, 'b', date '2018-02-16' from dual union all
  6   select 2, 'a', date '2018-02-17' from dual union all
  7   select 2, 'b', date '2018-02-16' from dual union all
  8   select 3, 'a', date '2018-02-17' from dual union all
  9   select 3, 'a', date '2018-02-16' from dual union all
 10   select 4, 'd', date '2018-02-16' from dual
 11  )
 12  select id, code, datum
 13  from test
 14  where id in (select id
 15               From test
 16               where datum between date '2018-02-16' and date '2018-02-18'
 17               group by id
 18               having count(distinct code) > 1)
 19  order by id, datum desc;

        ID C DATUM
---------- - ----------
         2 a 17.02.2018
         2 b 16.02.2018

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `COUNT( DISTINCT code ) OVER ( PARTITION BY id )` analytic function to get your answer using only one table scan:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/71b631/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( ID, Code, "DATE" ) AS
SELECT 1, 'A', DATE '2018-02-19' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'B', DATE '2018-02-18' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'B', DATE '2018-02-17' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'B', DATE '2018-02-16' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'A', DATE '2018-02-17' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'B', DATE '2018-02-16' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'A', DATE '2018-02-17' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'A', DATE '2018-02-16' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'D', DATE '2018-02-16' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT ID,
       Code,
       "DATE"
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         COUNT( DISTINCT code ) OVER ( PARTITION BY id ) AS num_changes
  FROM   table_name t
  WHERE  "DATE" BETWEEN DATE '2018-02-16'
                    AND DATE '2018-02-19'
)
WHERE num_changes > 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/71b631/1/0)**:

```
| ID | CODE |                 DATE |
|----|------|----------------------|
|  1 |    A | 2018-02-19T00:00:00Z |
|  1 |    B | 2018-02-18T00:00:00Z |
|  1 |    B | 2018-02-17T00:00:00Z |
|  1 |    B | 2018-02-16T00:00:00Z |
|  2 |    A | 2018-02-17T00:00:00Z |
|  2 |    B | 2018-02-16T00:00:00Z |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT ID,
       Code,
       "DATE"
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         COUNT( DISTINCT code ) OVER ( PARTITION BY id ) AS num_changes
  FROM   table_name t
  WHERE  "DATE" BETWEEN DATE '2018-02-16'
                    AND DATE '2018-02-18'
)
WHERE num_changes > 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/71b631/1/1)**:

```
| ID | CODE |                 DATE |
|----|------|----------------------|
|  2 |    A | 2018-02-17T00:00:00Z |
|  2 |    B | 2018-02-16T00:00:00Z |
```