# Oracle list only records that changed

Tags: sql, oracle, gaps-and-islands

I have the following code that produces a table as shown in the image:

```
with test (code, datum) as
      (select 600, date '2018-02-01' from dual union all
       select 600, date '2018-02-02' from dual union all
       select 0, date '2018-02-03' from dual union all
       select 0, date '2018-02-04' from dual union all
       select 0, date '2018-02-05' from dual union all
       select 600, date '2018-02-06' from dual union all
       select 600, date '2018-02-07' from dual union all
       select 0, date '2018-02-08' from dual union all
       select 0, date '2018-02-09' from dual
      )

    select * from test;
```

I have tried the following, but does not return what I need.

```
    select * from (
    select test.*, min(datum) over (partition by code order by code) as min_date, 
    max(datum) over (partition by code order by code) as max_date  
    from test) where min_date = datum;
```

[image]

What I would like to achieve is list only the records where a change occurs on the 'code' column (before and after record where the change occurs).

So the result set should look like this:

```
02/FEB/18 00:00:00  600
03/FEB/18 00:00:00  0
05/FEB/18 00:00:00  0
06/FEB/18 00:00:00  600
07/FEB/18 00:00:00  600
08/FEB/18 00:00:00  0
```

I referenced this question, but it does not address the same issue I have.

[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52554883/select-rows-when-column-value-change-in-between-date-in-oracle)

Any help appreciated, thank you.

**UPDATE:**

This is closer to what I would like to achieve. I can list all rows where columns code and change are not the same. However, I need to list the record after where these values are different as well.

```
with test (code, datum) as
  (select 600, date '2018-02-01' from dual union all
   select 600, date '2018-02-02' from dual union all
   select 0, date '2018-02-03' from dual union all
   select 0, date '2018-02-04' from dual union all
   select 0, date '2018-02-05' from dual union all
   select 600, date '2018-02-06' from dual union all
   select 600, date '2018-02-07' from dual union all
   select 0, date '2018-02-08' from dual union all
   select 0, date '2018-02-09' from dual
  )
  ,y1 as (
    select test.datum, test.code, lead(code) over (order by datum) as change
    from test
  )
select * from y1;
```

[image]

[image]

The final result set should contain the highlighted rows only.

[image]

**UPDATE 2:**

I think I may have got it right, still need to verify but this seems to work:

```
 with test (code, datum) as
      (select 600, date '2018-02-01' from dual union all
       select 600, date '2018-02-02' from dual union all
       select 0, date '2018-02-03' from dual union all
       select 0, date '2018-02-04' from dual union all
       select 0, date '2018-02-05' from dual union all
       select 600, date '2018-02-06' from dual union all
       select 600, date '2018-02-07' from dual union all
       select 0, date '2018-02-08' from dual union all
       select 0, date '2018-02-09' from dual
      )
      ,y1 as (
        select test.datum, test.code, lag(nvl(code,code)) over (order by datum) as after, lead(nvl(code,code)) over (order by datum) as before
        from test
      )
      select * from y1 where code != before or code != after;
```

Comment: `What I would like to achieve is list only the records where a change occurs on the 'code' column` -- Whats the mechanism to identify the change occured on the column ?

Comment: Essentially, we use the datum column which is ordered in ascending order. So it will start from the first row, and when there is a change in code it will print the row before the change as well as the row after. In short display the old and new values of code as it moves through time (datum).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script produced the expected result set:

```
with test (code, datum) as
      (select 600, date '2018-02-01' from dual union all
       select 600, date '2018-02-02' from dual union all
       select 0, date '2018-02-03' from dual union all
       select 0, date '2018-02-04' from dual union all
       select 0, date '2018-02-05' from dual union all
       select 600, date '2018-02-06' from dual union all
       select 600, date '2018-02-07' from dual union all
       select 0, date '2018-02-08' from dual union all
       select 0, date '2018-02-09' from dual
      )
      ,y1 as (
        select test.datum, test.code, lag(nvl(code,code)) over (order by datum) as after, lead(nvl(code,code)) over (order by datum) as before
        from test
      )
      select * from y1 where code != before or code != after;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would help i couldnot see any relevance to sort out the expected output in your question.

```
with test (code, datum) as
  (select 600, date '2018-02-01' from dual union all
   select 600, date '2018-02-02' from dual union all
   select 0, date '2018-02-03' from dual union all
   select 0, date '2018-02-04' from dual union all
   select 0, date '2018-02-05' from dual union all
   select 600, date '2018-02-06' from dual union all
   select 600, date '2018-02-07' from dual union all
   select 0, date '2018-02-08' from dual union all
   select 0, date '2018-02-09' from dual
  )
  ,y1 as (
    select test.datum, test.code, lead(code) over (order by datum) as change
    from test
    UNION 
    select test.datum, test.code, lag(code) over (order by datum) as change
    from test

  )
select * from y1 
where change = 600;
```

Comment: Thank you for the code, that gave me an idea and I think I got what I wanted. I have posted an updated version.

Comment: XING, it is wrong answer, you should remove or edit it.

Comment: @akk0rd87 I appreciate your patience to read through the question and then evaluating my answer as incorrect. However i would had also `appreciated` you if you would had read my comments and OP comments. I already wrote my answer was near to what user expected and he mentioned as well that it helped. Not sure if you have some answer which could help user then please post it. SO is not a community just to give right answer, it also important if your directions could help someone to reach to a conclusion resolving the issue.